# Make <td> stay inside window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

So I made a table with some content, but when one of my strings is very long, it goes out of my window. How can this be changed?
thought by defining a `max-width: 80%;` that it couldn't exceed this.
also tried to give `td, th` = `width: 240px;`. but it still happens?

Then I tried to implement something like this
`word-wrap: break-word;` but that made no difference.

```css
.tableTheme {
    background: #0d5dd4;
    color: white;
}

.tableWidth {
    max-width: 80%;
}

.tableWidth td,
th {
    width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="tableWidth">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="tableTheme">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Test Suite Collection ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Test Suite Collection Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Test Suite ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Test Suite Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Test Case ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Test Case Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>TSC</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>TS</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>TC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>WHEN_I_HAVE_A_VERY_LONG_STRING_IT_DOESN'T_FIT_ONE_WINDW_ANYMORE_WHEN_I_HAVE_A_VERY_LONG_STRING_IT_DOESN'T_FIT_ONE_WINDW_ANYMORE_WHEN_I_HAVE_A_VERY_LONG_STRING_IT_DOESN'T_FIT_ONE_WINDW_ANYMORE</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>TS</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>TC</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you adding `width` for `td` and `th`?

Comment: Have you looked at [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout), the `fixed` property-value often solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

it wlll work

```css
.tableTheme {
  background: #0d5dd4;
  color: white;
}

.tableWidth {
  max-width: 80%;
}

.tableWidth td,
th {
  width: 240px;
}
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="tableWidth">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead class="tableTheme">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Test Suite Collection ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Test Suite Collection Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Test Suite ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Test Suite Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Test Case ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Test Case Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>TSC</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>TS</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>TC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>
            WHEN_I_HAVE_A_VERY_LONG_STRING_IT_DOESN'T_FIT_ONE_WINDW_ANYMORE_WHEN_I_HAVE_A_VERY_LONG_STRING_IT_DOESN'T_FIT_ONE_WINDW_ANYMORE_WHEN_I_HAVE_A_VERY_LONG_STRING_IT_DOESN'T_FIT_ONE_WINDW_ANYMORE
          </td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>TS</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>TC</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lol thanks, thought it was easy... was on the right track though! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Usually long strings do contain spaces between the words, so they will break. But if not, `word-break: break-all;` does what you obviously want:

```css
.tableTheme {
    background: #0d5dd4;
    color: white;
}

.tableWidth {
    max-width: 80%;
}

.tableWidth td,
th {
    width: 240px;
}
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="tableWidth">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="tableTheme">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Test Suite Collection ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Test Suite Collection Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Test Suite ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Test Suite Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Test Case ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Test Case Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>TSC</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>TS</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>TC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>WHEN_I_HAVE_A_VERY_LONG_STRING_IT_DOESN'T_FIT_ONE_WINDW_ANYMORE_WHEN_I_HAVE_A_VERY_LONG_STRING_IT_DOESN'T_FIT_ONE_WINDW_ANYMORE_WHEN_I_HAVE_A_VERY_LONG_STRING_IT_DOESN'T_FIT_ONE_WINDW_ANYMORE</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>TS</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>TC</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```